# ASP.NET vNext resource file format

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

Noticed that ASP.NET vNext is using JSON for the web.config files.

Is vNext also going to favor JSON for the resource (resx) file format over the current XML format?

Comment: If no answer comes up I guess you could install it and see for yourself :).

Comment: Guess I could. Since things are pretty much in alpha still and could change, I'd like to hear from someone close to the team, the direction they plan to take.

Comment: Resx files are the standard in .NET and aren't limited to ASP.NET. They'd break away from the standard if they used a `resources.json` or similar. That being said, I wouldn't be surprised at all if they did. I'd welcome it.

Comment: This answer to another similar question appears to at least partially answer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25725388/asp-net-vnext-localization-resx