# ASP.NET vNext - Localization (.resx)

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2015

How can I use resx files for localization with ASP.NET vNext (cloud optimize mode) and how can I set culture for current thread?

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture
```

`CurrentCulture` and `CurrentUICulture` properties are missing. I have VS 2015 CTP3.

Pavel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The localization story for vNext is not yet ready. We are still working on it.

EDIT (Feb-28-2015):

Localization will be available in the RC/Beta4 release. Here is a prototype https://github.com/DamianEdwards/i18nStarterWeb. I expect things to start showing up in the dev branch over the next few weeks.

Comment: Do you have some specification, how it will be localization work. Do you plan changes?

Comment: We don't have that yet. Design haven't started.

Comment: @yishai-galatzer do you have any update on that ? There's Strings.resx in EF7, how it works ?

Comment: Yes we generate resources into the main assembly (both in ef and mvc) but we didn't get to the point of how localized resources are consumed in a localized app.

Comment: Damian Edwards works on prototype, check out is repo on github https://github.com/DamianEdwards/i18nStarterWeb

Comment: @YishaiGalatzer Hi, is there any news on returning resx support in VS? CTP6 seems just ignoring resx-files completely: it doesn't generate c# code and doesn't embed resources in dlls.

Comment: Beta4 is RC, CTP6 is beta3.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are looking for in vnext has been moved onto CultureInfo directly:

```
        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture
        CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture
```

Comment: When I rebuild project, i get error about properties are read only. I temporarily use System.Reflection for set CurrentThread.CurrentCulture and CurrentUICulture.